# Gift Wrapping Algorithm not working properly

Tags: java, algorithm, vb6, convex-hull

I am trying to implement this Gift Wrapping Algorithm ([yoshihitoyagi](http://yoshihitoyagi.com/projects/mesh/convexhull/giftwrapping/GiftWrapping.java)!) done in java, in VB6. I'm pretty sure I have done this properly, but for some reason, it will not work. The returned arrays only have 1 element. I was hoping somebody could take a look (a new set of eyes) and let me know if I am blatently missing something.

Here is my code:

```
Function small(ByVal Current As Integer, ByVal smallest As Integer, ByVal i As Integer) As Boolean
Dim xa, ya, xb, yb, val As Integer

xa = xPoints(smallest) - xPoints(Current)
xb = xPoints(i) - xPoints(Current)
ya = yPoints(smallest) - yPoints(Current)
yb = yPoints(i) - yPoints(Current)

val = xa * yb - xb * ya

If val > 0 Then
    small = True
ElseIf val < 0 Then
    small = False
Else
    If (xa * xb + ya * yb) < 0 Then
        small = False
    Else
        If (xa * xa + ya * ya) > (xb * xb + yb * yb) Then
            small = True
        Else
            small = False
        End If
    End If
End If

End Function

Sub CreateContours1()
Dim Min, i, num, smallest, Current, contourcount2 As Integer
Dim xPoints2(), yPoints2() As Long

'Find leftmost lowest point
Min = 1
For i = 1 To contourCount
    If yPoints(i) = yPoints(Min) Then
        If xPoints(i) < xPoints(Min) Then
            Min = i
        End If
    ElseIf yPoints(i) < yPoints(Min) Then
        Min = i
    End If
Next

Debug.Print "Min: " & Min
Current = Min
num = 1

Do
    contourcount2 = contourcount2 + 1
    ReDim Preserve xPoints2(contourcount2)
    ReDim Preserve yPoints2(contourcount2)
    xPoints2(num) = xPoints(Current)
    yPoints2(num) = yPoints(Current)
    Debug.Print "num: " & num & ", current: " & Current & "(" & xPoints(Current) & ", " & yPoints(Current) & ")"
    num = num + 1
    smallest = 1
    If smallest = Current Then
        smallest = 1
    End If

    For i = 1 To contourCount
        If (Current = i) Or (smallest = i) Then
            GoTo continue_loop
        End If
        If small(Current, smallest, i) Then
            smallest = i
        End If
    Next
    Current = smallest
continue_loop:
Loop While Current <> Min

End Sub
```

All my arrays are starting at 1. So if you see any differences between 1's and 0's that is why.

I understand this is a lot, but any help would be so appreciated.

THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say because I don't know if there are other variables that might be at class/module scope that are not shown, but you may have some undeclared variables in use.

1. Use Option Explicit and see if any compile errors show up.  In particular `contourCount` doesn't seem to be declared.
2. You need to declare each variables type explictly.

This:

```
Dim Min, i, num, smallest, Current, contourcount2 As Integer 
Dim xPoints2(), yPoints2() As Long
```

Is really this:

```
Dim Min As Variant, i As Variant, num As Variant, smallest As Variant, Current As Variant, contourcount2 As Integer 
Dim xPoints2() As Variant, yPoints2() As Long
```

So you should change to this:

```
Dim Min As Long, i As Long, num As Long, smallest As Long, Current As Long, contourcount2 As Long 
Dim xPoints2() As Long, yPoints2() As Long
```

Also note that I changed them all to Long.  There is almost no reason to use the Integer (2-byte) data type anymore in VB6.

**EDIT1:**

> All my arrays are starting at 1. So if you see any differences between
>   1's and 0's that is why.

Are you aware that your redim preserves do not preserve your low bounds of 1 unless you explicitly state it?  So `ReDim Preserve xPoints2(contourcount2)' allocates a "zeroeth" slot.  You can use 'ReDim Preserve xPoints2(1 to contourcount2)' if you want to start that array at 1.

**EDIT2:**

Outside your Do loop you have `Current = Min`

Next inside your Do Loop you have

```
smallest = 1     
If smallest = Current Then         
   smallest = 1     
End If
```

This means on **every** iteration smallest is 1.

Next you have For loop that always starts at 1:

```
For i = 1 To contourCount         
    If (Current = i) Or (smallest = i) Then
        GoTo continue_loop         
    End If
    'the rest ommited because you never get here
Next
```

Note that small is **always** 1 so you always branch.

And finally you branch is this:

```
continue_loop: 
Loop While Current <> Min
```

Current is still 1 and as long as your points are such that when Min was calculated it was not at pos 1 then you will immediately satisfy the Loop condition and exit.

Comment: tcarvin, contourCount is declared globally. I tried declaring each variable explicitly and it did not see to change the outcome.

Comment: I knew declaring each variable explicitly would not change your behavior but it is a best-practice so was worth including.